# C# OfType in Java Android

Tags: java, c#, android, itext

I'm writing an app using iText 5G, I have seen a piece of code to doesn't allow that tables split at page end but that code was written in C#, I have converted almost of all the code to Java but I'm stuck in one line that I don't know the equivalent in Java.

The C# code:

```
public override IList<iTextSharp.text.IElement> End(iTextSharp.tool.xml.IWorkerContext ctx, iTextSharp.tool.xml.Tag tag, IList<iTextSharp.text.IElement> currentContent)
{
    string keeprowstogetherattr = "keeprowstogether";
    var retval = base.End(ctx, tag, currentContent);
    if (tag.Attributes.ContainsKey(keeprowstogetherattr) && tag.Attributes[keeprowstogetherattr] == "true")
    {
        foreach (PdfPTable table in retval.OfType<PdfPTable>())
        {
            table.KeepRowsTogether(0);
        }
    }
    return retval;
}
```

My Java code at the moment:

```
public List<Element> End(WorkerContext ctx, Tag tag, List<Element> currentContent)
{
    {
        String keeprowstogetherattr = "keeprowstogether";
        List<Element> retval = super.end(ctx, tag, currentContent);
        if (tag.getAttributes().containsKey(keeprowstogetherattr) && tag.getAttributes().get(keeprowstogetherattr) == "true");
        {
            for (PdfPTable table : retval.OfType<PdfPTable>())
            {
                table.keepRowsTogether(0);
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

The line that I'm stuck:

```
PdfPTable table : retval.OfType<PdfPTable>()
```

I don't know the equivalent to C#'s OfType in Java.
Thanks.

EDIT: My `min` API is 19, so stream() doesn't work.

Comment: @poke: This is not a duplicate because the OP can't use the Streams API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use the stream filters, the simplest way is probably to do an `instanceof` check inside the for loop:

```
for(Element e: retval) {
    if(e instanceof PdfPTable) {
        ((PdfPTable) e).keepRowsTogether(0);
    }
}
```

As stylistic notes, you should name your methods starting with lowercase letters (`end`), and that `keeprowstogetherattr` should be a constant field named `KEEP_ROWS_TOGETHER_ATTR` (or better yet, `ATTR_KEEP_ROWS_TOGETHER`) in both C# and Java.

Comment: You night want to change `keepRowsTogether(0)` into `setKeepRowsTogether(false)`.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Perhaps. I have absolutely no idea what the API involved is.

Comment: And your question answered the question adequately, which is why I gave you an up-vote. I just wanted to comment because someone might copy/paste the snippet, and then complain that "it doesn't work" :D

Comment: @BrunoLowagie iText G5 - XMLWorker